# Adding Files and Select Multiple Targets in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I have over 200 projects in my XCode and when I add a new file or class I have to select each target one by one to add it to it.  Is there a way to select multiple targets instead?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the awesome **[AllTargets](https://github.com/poboke/AllTargets)** Xcode plug-in by *poboke* [available on Github](https://github.com/poboke/AllTargets) (works with Xcode 5+).

[image]

**Manual build and install**

> 1. Download source code and open AllTargets.xcodeproj with Xcode.
> 2. Select "Edit Scheme" and set "Build Configuration" as "Release"
> 3. Build it. It automatically installs the plugin into the correct directory.
> 4. Restart Xcode. (Make sure that the Xcode process is terminated entirely)

**Manual uninstall**

Delete the following directory:

```
$HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/AllTargets.xcplugin
```

---

↳ [Tutorial](http://www.poboke.com/study/write-a-xcode-plugin-to-auto-select-all-targets.html) on how the plugin was created (Chinese).